# Add weighted edge to a graph in Mathematica 8

Tags: graphs-and-networks, version-8

Is it possible to add an edge with a specific weight to a Mathematica Graph object?
The function `EdgeAdd` has no option for the weights, nor the `AddEdge` function from the `GraphUtilities` package.

I want to modify the edge `1-4` of the `CompleteGraph[5]` for example, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

For V9 and up. (you haven't specified your version in your question)

```
g = CompleteGraph[4]; 
PropertyValue[{g, UndirectedEdge[1, 2]}, EdgeWeight] = 2;
MatrixForm@Normal@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Ooooooooookay. I'm out!

Comment: @Öskå The introduction of `PropertyWhatever[]` in v9 added a nice layer to access graph properties. It's still immature in my opinion.

Comment: Well, still better than what I did..

Comment: No sorry, this does not work in Mathematica 8!

Comment: @linello If you Mma version isn't the current one you should state that in your question! ;D

Comment: Some ideas for Mathematica 8? Meanwhile I switched to directly changing the entries of the weighted adjacency matrix but this is definitely not the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: @linello `Graph[]` was in its childhood in V8. If you're planning to use it extensively I strongly suggest to upgrade at least to v9. Messing with the WAM isn't that bad ..

Comment: @linello My answer bellow works in _v8_, I deleted after I saw how easy it could be in _v9_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you intend to do with `EdgeAdd` thus I will only answer the *"I want to modify the edge 1-4 of the `CompleteGraph[5]`"* question.

Here I modify the edge `1 <-> 4` and `1 <-> 2` for generalisation purposes:

```
g = CompleteGraph[5];
weightsVal = {a, b}; (* in the same order as {1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2}*)
weights = ReplacePart[Array[1 &, Length@EdgeList@g], 
  Rule @@@ Thread@{Flatten[Position[EdgeList@g, #] & /@ {1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2}], weightsVal}]
Graph[EdgeList@g, AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates], 
 EdgeWeight -> weights, 
 EdgeLabels -> Rule @@@ Thread@{EdgeList@g, weights}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
% // WeightedAdjacencyMatrix // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & b & 1 & a & 1 \\
>  b & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  a & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$